# RNA isolation from Drosophila head

Tags: molecular-biology, rna

I need to isolate RNA from Drosophila head. I basically chop the head off and first homogenize it with a homogenizer (similar to this: http://www.omni-inc.com/omni-tissue-homogenizer-th-package-p-11.html) and further homogenize it with 22G needle in TRIzol reagent. I use TRIzol RNA isolation for larvae brain a lot and have no problem with the method itself. However, with adult I got really low RNA concentration which is weird.

I thought that maybe I have problem with homogenization itself, or I overlook something (such as extra centrifugation or different kind of homogenization etc). Does anybody have experience with it? 
Thanks.

Comment: You mean you have not a lot of RNA compared to whole larvae? Don't forget that in larvae a lot of gene expression is going on compared to the brains of developed flies. And the heads are a lot smaller, too. What does low concentration in terms of numbers mean?

Comment: I isolate RNA from larvae brain so not whole larvae. For example, from approx. 150 larvae after DNase treatment, I got more or less 120 ug RNA. 

For the very first time I have tried with adult. I used 220 adult heads and after DNase treatment concentraion of RNA was 52 ug. For me this result indicates a problem.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood that. How is the quality of the RNA?

Comment: I measured with nanodrop and these are the ratios for adult RNA: 260/280= 2.17 and 260/230: 2.21

For larvae I usually get also more less these ratios.

Comment: That sounds not bad for me, at least you have no quality problem. Do the heads dissolve completely?

Comment: Good way to get heads off (if doing many flies of the same genotype/treatment etc.) is to put whole flies in a safe-lock eppendorf, put them in liquid nitrogen, drop the eppendorf on the desk a few times and the heads should have fallen off and you can collect them - ideal if you are putting them in liquid nitrogen anyway (as is common with RNA extraction).

Comment: Yes quality is ok but I need more RNA, thats the issue unfortunately. I also homogenize larvae brain with 22G needle and works well. This time after homogenizer, I did with 22G needle also, it was going up and down easily. After phase separation with chloroform, there was a huge trash phase.

I did not do any liquid nitrogen step before homogenization. Do you think it can be the problem? I simply make them sleep on ice and then got their heads.

Comment: You say that 150 larval brains give you ~120 ug RNA. Do you have an idea of the amount of total RNA that can be extracted from a single brain?
I have posted a question here:
http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28078/how-much-total-rna-can-be-extracted-from-drosophila-brain

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like a homogenization problem. Nonetheless you can try this:

- Suspend the heads in trizol
- Homogenize by passing through **30/31G** needles ([insulin syringe](http://www.bd.com/us/diabetes/page.aspx?cat=7001&id=7253)) up to 10-15 times.
- Heating a little might help but I think it is unnecessary for these tissues.

Insulin syringe is much better than the hand held homogenizer. Freeze-thaw 1-2 times if you want (helps in homogenization).

During extraction you can add 5M LiCl (100µl) + Ethanol (1ml) to 400µl aqueous phase (instead of isopropanol), keep at -20⁰C for 1-2h before centrifuging. Alternatively you can add a little RNAse free glycogen to Isopropanol during precipitation.

PS: the liquid Nitrogen trick that rg255 mentioned is for quickly getting heads and avoiding the pain of dissecting each head.